# Как спарсить таблиицу с сайта на PHP?

Tags: php

Есть вот такая таблица, пока не понимаю как её спарсить

```
<table class="disconnection-table">
<thead>
<tr style="overflow: hidden;">
    <th colspan="4"></th>
    <th colspan="2">Начало отключения</th>
    <th colspan="2">Восстановление электроснабжения</th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
</tr>
<tr class="lastTrTd">
    <th class="region">Регион РФ</th>
    <th class="district">Административный район</th>
    <th class="location">Населенный пункт</th>
    <th class="object">Улица</th>
    <th class="">Дата</th>
    <th class="">Время</th>
    <th class="">Дата</th>
    <th class="">Время</th>
    <th class="branch">Филиал</th>
    <th class="res_title">РЭС</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>        
<tr id="ufid2226347" class="dE2BE8A80-CD36-43AF-9D5E-8ED10B4BD2FF" style="overflow: hidden;">
<td class="region">Москва</td>
<td class="district">Москва</td>
<td class="location">Москва</td>
<td class="object">Москва</td>
<td class="disconn-start-date">26.06.2023</td>
<td class="disconn-start-time">08:00</td>
<td class="disconn-end-date">26.06.2023</td>
<td class="disconn-end-time">17:00</td>
<td class="branch">Москва</td>
<td class="res_title">Москва</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: В чём конкретная проблема-то? Если не умеете парсить, то в интернете есть множество статей на эту тему

Comment: Не ответ, но вот это https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM может помочь